# Will addresses (in the stack) of an instruction from a program will ever change?

Tags: reverse-engineering, exploit

I'm beginner at low level exploiting. I'm practicing with simple buffer overflow (stack based). I'm using Kali Linux so when I `$objdump -d <program>` and it returns (let's say):

==================================================

0000000000400590: main

400590          push ...

400600          xor ...

400610          call ...

...

==================================================

I know it was a bad example, but my question is will the address `400590` sticks to `push ...` forever and address `400600` sticks to `xor ...` forever and the same with `400610`? Will a particular instruction of a program stick with an address forever?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the compiler/linker assigns code addresses, so those do not change unless the application is recompiled (or patched).

Comment: By the way, I want to ask for more info (because I'm a noob):
1. What if two programs use the same address
2. This is not very related to this topic and may sound like a stupid question to you. Sir, are instructions stored in stack, or they just going to be executed line by line by the CPU?

Comment: On nearly all operating systems nowadays, each process gets its own isolated address space, so several programs can use e.g. 0x400000 as their base address with no conflicts.